# how to retrieve parameter from jquery post

Tags: jquery, post

I'm retrieving parameters from the URL with jquery. There may be more than one parameter to retrieve. Then I take the parameters and feed them one by one to a $.post procedure. How do I retrieve the parameter inside the post code?

```
 var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
        var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');

        for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) 
        {
            $.post('php/get_victim.php', {name:sURLVariables[i]}, function(output){
                //I want to get the "name" variable inside here
            });
         }
```

Comment: Use a closure... (better yet, refactor the AJAX call to make one call with the list, rather than looping)

Comment: @tymeJV: Not sure what you mean. Can you show code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a closure and retain the variable being looped over:

```
for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
    (function(name) {
        $.post('php/get_victim.php', {name:name}, function(output) {
            //I want to get the "name" variable inside here
            console.log(name); //name from above
        });
    })(sURLVariables[i])
}
```